# copy text to clipboard using 'clipboard.js' without button

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard.js

I use the https://clipboardjs.com/ library to copy text to the clipboard.

In all examples, you need to press the button. But how to implement it without a button?

```
init_clipboard();
copy_to_clipboard ('mytext');
```

In clipboard.js example:

```
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn', {
    text: function() {
        return 'to be or not to be';
    }
});
```

with button

```
<button class="btn">Copy</button>
```

**But I want without a button and user activity**

Comment: If the user doesn't initiate the copy, how will they know their clipboard now contains text?

Comment: https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/issues/218 - "I would love to have this too but due to security restrictions imposed by browser vendors, user interaction is required in order copy/cut to work. A simulated click event using JavaScript does not work as this would enable clipboard poisoning."

Comment: Try: `clipboard.onClick()`. It looks like this library is using `document.execCommand(...)` which seems to work for copying without user intervention at least on Chrome.

Comment: I'd be interested if execCommand worked, I thought the browser requires a click event for it to work

Comment: @DominicTobias I've created [this snipped](https://jsbin.com/kupivadade/edit?html,js,console,output) and it works form me on Chrome.

Comment: @couzzi, maybe add a confirmation message?

Answer (score 17):

Clipboard.js creator here. Many people have asked for this featured but this is a security limitation imposed by various browsers. If you try to simulate a click event using JavaScript it will not work as well. All this is because of preventing clipboard poisoning.